# How to increase Foursquare Venue limit for getting all restaurants from Foursquare Venue API?

Tags: azure, foursquare

I am calling Foursquare Venue API for getting all food venues of London.

Used API is: `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=51.51121389999999,-0.11982439999997041&section=xxxx&**limit=11000**&oauth_token=xxxx`

It returns always random 100 venues. If I call it next time then it returns same venues instead of unique 100 venues.

How to get unique records for getting all venues? How to get all venues by increasing the limit?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of venues returned in an explore query can be found in our documentation: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore

Getting *all* the food venues in any geographic region isn't really something the Foursquare API is designed to do, but you can get different results if you modify your `ll` and/or `radius` params. Please keep in mind our [developer policies](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues#rules) against scraping though if you choose to do a sweeping approach.